# swift stop loop and continue it with a button

Tags: swift, macos, loops, cocoa

is it possible to stop an for in loop and continue it and the stopped position with a button.

i mean something like this:

```
for x in 0..<5 {

   if x == 3 {
      // show a button
      // this button have to be pressed
      // which do some tasks
      // when all tasks are finished > 
      // continue this loop at the stopped point
   } 
}
```

is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use a *semaphore*

Longer answer:

Your situation is an example of the more general case of how to pause some computation, saving its current state (local variables, call stack, etc.), and later to resume it from the same point, with all state restored.

Some languages/systems provide *coroutines* to support this, others the more esoteric *call with current continuation*, neither are available to you (currently) Swift...

What you do have is *Grand Central Dispatch* (GCD), provided in Swift through `Dispatch`, which provides support for executing concurrent asynchronous tasks and synchronisation between them. Other concurrency mechanisms such as `pthread` are also available, but GCD tends to be recommended.

Using GCD an outline of a solution is:

- Execute you loop as an asynchronous concurrent task. It must *not* be executing on the main thread or you will deadlock...
- When you wish to pause:

  - Create a semaphore
  - Start another async task to display the button, run the other jobs etc. This new task must *signal* the semaphore when it is finished. The new task may call the main thread to perform UI operations.
  - Your loop task *waits* on the semaphore, this will block the loop task until the button task signals it.

This may sound complicated but with Swift *block* syntax and `Dispatch` it is quite simple. However you do need to read up on GCD first!

Alternatively you can ask whether you can restructure your solution into multiple parts so saving/restoring the current state is not required. You might find designs such as *continuation passing style* useful, which again is quite easy using Swift's blocks.

HTH